# Why does Intent.createChooser() need a BroadcastReceiver and how to implement?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

The following snippet, called from my implementation of `onOptionsItemSelected()`, works nicely to carry the user from my app to a mail client with email address, subject and body pre-filled. I'm using this as a simple way to let the user give me feedback.

```
String uriText =
    "mailto:" + emailAddress +
    "?subject=" + subject +
    "&body=" + body;

Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(uriText));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Pick an email app:"));
```

When the mail app opens (on my Nexus S with Android 4.0.4), LogCat outputs the following, and I can't figure out why; Google and SO searches for *createChooser unregisterReceiver* seem fruitless, and I can't find many examples of `createChooser()` that also call `unregisterReceiver()` in a way that helps this situation.

> 04-08 21:26:19.094: E/ActivityThread(27894): Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@4150aac8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
>
> 04-08 21:26:19.094: E/ActivityThread(27894): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@4150aac8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
>
> 04-08 21:26:19.094: E/ActivityThread(27894):   at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:763)

This feels like an Android bug because my own code doesn't call `registerReceiver()`, so why is Android complaining that I need to call `unregisterReceiver()`?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with my nexus s 4.0.4

Comment: Does this happen in the emulator? If not, [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/POS_LeIim_U) could be related.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I see this as well on my Galaxy Nexus with 4.0.4, but only if there's only one option and the chooser doesn't appear.

This is a bug in Android source - not much you can do about it.  Their ResolverActivity registers a BroadcastReceiver, but doesn't always unregister it.

More detail:

Intent.createChooser() will start a ResolverActivity.  In onCreate(), the activity calls

```
mPackageMonitor.register(this, false);
```

mPackageMonitor is a BroadcastReceiver and within `register()` it registers itself on the activity.  Normally, the receiver is unregistered in `onStop()`.  However, later in `onCreate()` the code checks how many options the user can choose from.  If there's only one it calls `finish()`.  Since `finish()` is called in `onCreate()` the other lifecycle methods are never called and it jumps straight to `onDestroy()` - leaking the receiver.

I didn't see a bug for this in the Android issues database, so I [created one](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29399).

For more info you can see this in code:

- [ResolverActivity](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/app/ResolverActivity.java)
- [PackageMonitor](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/content/PackageMonitor.java)

As a side note, Google uses email as an example of when you wouldn't want to use a chooser so you may consider just launching the intent normally.  See the javadocs for [Intent#ACTION_CHOOSER](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/Intent.java).

Comment: Have you got a link reference for google saying don't use choose for email?

Comment: It's in the javadocs for Intent#ACTION_CHOOSER.  You can use the link above or look at them in Eclipse.

Comment: FYI, this seems to be happening on Android 4.4 regardless of how many options there are.  Change the intent type to "text/html" for example helps, but it also limits the number of apps that can actually be shared to.  Any idea why Android 4.4 is causing this?

Comment: Seems like there's a serious issue with Android 4.4 as the issue occurs on Youtube, Tumblr and various other apps.  Here's my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827280/on-android-api-19-4-4-the-intent-createchooser-method-causes-intentserviceleak/19827317#19827317

Answer (score 4):

Simple resolution of problem.

More info here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

```
Uri location = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+California");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, location);

PackageManager pkManager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = pkManager.queryIntentActivities(mapIntent, 0);

if (activities.size() > 1) {
    // Create and start the chooser
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(mapIntent, "Open with");
    startActivity(chooser);

  } else {
    startActivity( mapIntent );
}
```