# How to share internal storage file with Gmail Client

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail, android-contentprovider

I am trying to share my internal storage file via Gmail client on my Moto Razr, but every time I sent to my test gmail account, I got everything except attachment.

This is how I invoke and start gmail, while add file as attachment.

```
private void saveDaily() {
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.setType("text/plain");

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { loadEmailAddress() });
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Daily");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Daily Log");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
uris.add(saveDaily2File("dailyRecord.txt"));
Log.d(TAG_D, "Size: " + uris.size());
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send email"));
}
```

This is how I implement my customized content provider.

```
public class SavedFileProvider extends ContentProvider {

private static final String TAG_D = "ContentProvider";
private static final HashMap<String, String> MIME_TYPES = new HashMap<String, String>();

static {
MIME_TYPES.put(".txt", "text/plain");
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
String path = uri.toString();

for (String extension : MIME_TYPES.keySet()) {
    if (path.endsWith(extension)) {
    return (MIME_TYPES.get(extension));
    }
}

return (null);
}

@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode)
    throws FileNotFoundException {
Log.d(TAG_D, "openFile()");

File f = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), uri.getPath());

Log.d(TAG_D, f.getAbsolutePath());
if (f.exists()) {
    return (ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f,
        ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));
}

throw new FileNotFoundException(uri.getPath());
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri url, String[] projection, String selection,
    String[] selectionArgs, String sort) {
throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues initialValues) {
throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String where,
    String[] whereArgs) {
throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");
}

private void copy(InputStream in, File dst) throws IOException {
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;

while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
}

in.close();
out.close();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
Log.d(TAG_D, "onCreate()");
File f = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "dailyRecord.txt");

if (!f.exists()) {
    AssetManager assets = getContext().getResources().getAssets();

    try {
    copy(assets.open("dailyRecord.txt"), f);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("FileProvider", "Exception copying from assets", e);

    return (false);
    }
}
return (true);
}
```

}

Then, I add the following lines in my AndroidManifest.xml File.

```
<provider
        android:name=".SavedFileProvider"
        android:authorities="Package Path here"
        android:exported="true"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:multiprocess="true" >
</provider>
```

I wonder what I am missing here.

I have check the link:[Link1](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/ContentProvider/Files/src/com/commonsware/android/cp/files/FileProvider.java), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170386/create-and-share-a-file-from-internal-storage)

Comment: Can you check if your methods getType() and query( Uri uri, String[] projections, String arg2, String[] arg3, String arg4 ) are being called ? If so, I can provide you with some code so that will work both gmail and default email client.

Comment: I'll check on that. Thanks.

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377373/how-to-put-a-video-file-in-android-custom-content-provider

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider android:name="com.myapp.main.MyContentProvider" android:authorities="com.myapp.main"></provider>
```

Button click:

```
        public void onClick(View v) {

            List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
             Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
             shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
             Uri theUri = Uri.parse("content://com.myapp.main/"+srcImage);
             List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
             int i=0;
             List<ResolveInfo> reInfoToDelete = new ArrayList<ResolveInfo>();
             if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
                    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {
                        String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                        Intent targetedShareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        targetedShareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
                        targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share file");
                        if (packageName.equals("com.google.android.gm")){
                             targetedShareIntent.setType("image/png");

                             targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "some text");
                             targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, theUri);
                             targetedShareIntent.setPackage(packageName);
                             targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);

                        }
                    }



                    startActivity(targetedShareIntents.remove(0));
               }
        }
```

My Content Provider Class

```
    public class MyContentProvider extends ContentProvider implements PipeDataWriter<InputStream>{

    @Override
    public AssetFileDescriptor openAssetFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
        //Adapt this to your code
        AssetManager am = getContext().getAssets();
        String file_name = "path/"+uri.getLastPathSegment();
        if(file_name == null)
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
        try {
            afd = am.openFd(file_name);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return afd;//super.openAssetFile(uri, mode);
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeDataToPipe(ParcelFileDescriptor arg0, Uri arg1,
            String arg2, Bundle arg3, InputStream arg4) {
        // Transfer data from the asset to the pipe the client is reading.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int n;
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(arg0.getFileDescriptor());
        try {
            while ((n=arg4.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                fout.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("InstallApk", "Failed transferring", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                arg4.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            try {
                fout.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this also work for dynamically generated files or only for bundled assets?