# Send email with attachment from internal storage

Tags: android

I create file on the internal storage as suggested by android docs. To be accurate the file is created under a specific directory in the internal storage. I do this using the mode world_readable mode. Then later on i try to attach the file using email program. I was able to get the file attached, however sending the email failed (does not seem to be to load the file) i am sure it is internal storage/permission thingy.

Anyone knows how to fix it or a working example? It will suck to have convert everything on external storage.

Thank you

Ps:I checked other threads and they don't seem to have solutions (old threads)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587917/trying-to-attach-a-file-from-sd-card-to-email

Comment: r u able to see the file on email ?

Comment: @Stacks28. The problem is  I am acttaching from internal storage. SD won't do me help

Comment: Yes I see the file in the email but sending would fail. I can't even open the file in the email!

Comment: were u able to achieve this ??

Comment: Yes, I found it depends on the email program used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm assuming you are trying to send the file as an email attachment
>   using intents.
>
> The reason why the file is empty is that the email app does not have
>   access to the file in /data/data/package_name/myfile_name, due to
>   Androids security model (the /data/data/package_name directory is
>   private to your app).
>
> In order to add the file as an attachment, you need to write it to
>   public storage (such as the SD card) so the email app can access it.

Comment: So no way I can do it from internal storage even if I have set the mode to world readable

Comment: @Snake You can use internal storage too, by using Provider. Read the given answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482310/how-to-share-internal-storage-file-with-gmail-client

Answer (score 14):

It is possible to share a file from your apps local storage to another application (such as email attachment) by granting temporary permissions to read that file as part of the share intent.

Step 1: Add a file provider to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<applicaton>
     ....
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.your.package.name.fileprovider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

Step 2: Add a file res/xml/filepaths.xml with the path to the file in local app storage that you want to share:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="myFolder" path="Folder/"/>
</paths>
```

Step 3: In your java code create the file sharing intent:

```
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject");
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your message");

    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    String shareName = new String(pathToFile + filename);
    File shareFile = new File(shareName);
    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.your.package.name.fileprovider", shareFile);
    uris.add(contentUri);
    shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

    // Grant temporary read permission to the content URI
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    String msgStr = "Share...";
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, msgStr));
```

If you have any problems with it see the docs here
https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file.html for further details.

Comment: how do you include files from project in "files" directory?
in your example, what's "filePath"?

Comment: @jackal You have to mention the name of the file(to be shared)'s parent directory in path. ie. in place of `Folder/`

Comment: After this answer, I had to use the permissions code from the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18332000/3886821