# Intent.ACTION_SEND PDF file from internal storage only works to some apps

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, printing, bluetooth

I'm trying to print a PDF file from my app's internal storage by sending it with an Intent.ACTION_SEND to the PrinterShare app (I've bought the premium version which claims to be able to print files from apps' internal storage).

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21305564/956975), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13683322/956975) and am copying my file to internal cache thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12188993/956975) and it seems that the PrinterShare app is getting my file, but not "completely" - it can't render the file and when I print, it just pushes out an empty file.

With the share intent, I can choose other apps like Gmail and plain Bluetooth and then I can send the PDF file as an email attachment or over Bluetooth to my personal phone and it renders perfectly. It's just when I try to share it to Google Photos, Hangouts and then also the PrinterShare app, that something goes weirdly wrong.

So how do you debug a problem that only happens sometimes?

Earlier on in my code I create the file in internal storage like this:

```
                val savePdf = File(view.filesDir, "printthis.pdf")
```

This is my share intent construction (Kotlin):

```
override fun printPdf() {
        copyFileToInternal()
        val uri = Uri.parse("content://my.package.android.app/printthis.pdf")
        Log.d("Print PDF from $uri")
        val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        shareIntent.type = "image/*"
        shareIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
        (view as Context).startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Print PDF"))
    }
```

This is the `copyFileToInternal` function:

```
private fun copyFileToInternal() {
    try {
        val inputStream = (view as Context).openFileInput("pop.pdf")

        val cacheDir = (view).cacheDir
        val outFile = File(cacheDir, "pop.pdf")
        val os = FileOutputStream(outFile.absolutePath)
        val buff = ByteArray(1024)
        var len: Int
        len = inputStream.read(buff)
        while (len > 0) {
            os.write(buff, 0, len)
            len = inputStream.read(buff)
        }
        os.flush()
        os.close()
        inputStream.close()

    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Log.e("Could not copy file to internal cache. ", e)
    }
}
```

The only customisation on my `ContentProvider` is the `openFile` function:

```
@Throws(FileNotFoundException::class)
    override fun openFile(uri: Uri, mode: String): ParcelFileDescriptor? {
        val cacheDir = context.cacheDir
        val privateFile = File(cacheDir, "printthis.pdf")
        return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(privateFile, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY)
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: First, the MIME type of PDF is not `image/*`. Second, call `getFD().sync()` on your `FileOutputStream` after `flush()` and before `close()`, to ensure that all bytes are written to disk before continuing. Third, please ensure that this I/O is performed on a background thread. Fourth, your problem might be in the `ContentProvider` that you are not showing in your question.

Comment: Ah CommonsWare, you always come to the rescue when we miss silly things like MIME types. :) I've added the function I'm overriding in my custom ContentProvider

Comment: You might consider switching to using `FileProvider`, rather than rolling your own provider, and see if that helps.

Comment: Your earlier suggestions now renders the PDF in the PrinterShare app, but now I have a problem actually connecting to the printer (#hardwarehassles)

Comment: Try unplugging and replugging in the Bluetooth cable. :-)

Comment: You are a genius. :p