# how to fetch file from internal storage

Tags: android, file, filepath

my app generates text files and store them in internal storage.
there is no problem in reading and writing files but it was throwing exception `File not found(no such file or directory )` when i try to send file to laptop using(wlan) ftp.

then after debugging i got that it was a problem of file path. so i hard-coded  file path like this

### create and write file

```
 String path=context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();

             File file = new File(path + File.separator + fileName);
             RandomAccessFile rf = new RandomAccessFile(file,"rws"); 
             file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                Log.d("Created In",path);// in log path i found "/data/data/com.meta.Myapp/files"

                byte[] text = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                rf.readFully(text);
                rf.seek(0);
                rf.writeBytes(data);
                rf.write(text);
                Log.d("write","writing file...");
                rf.close();
```

### client side code to send file

```
  sock = new Socket("192.168.2.2", 21); 
          // sendfile

                String path="/data/data/com.meta.Myapp/files";

                Log.d("Fetching From",path);

                File myFile = new File ( path+ File.separator + fname); 
                byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
                Log.d("Sending","Sending in progress");
                os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                os.flush();

              sock.close();
```

now this is working fine with no problem. but i should not use hardcoded file path. so how to get filepath to fetch file. as client part runs in AsyncTask<> i cant use  `Context.getFilesDir().getPath()` and i dont know how to pass context to AsyncTask<> so how do i solve this problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170386/create-and-share-a-file-from-internal-storage

Comment: completely different example

Comment: no such file  or directory means your file or directory is not created or even if it created you may calling it other directory or file which not exist so my advice is first check d file which is generating through your code then chek your calling same file from sharing code?

Comment: fname is my file name

Comment: i checked file is created by reading it from another activity

Comment: you do not have to get path inside AsyncTask, you can get path inside the Activity and then pass it to AsyncTask from which you are sending request to AsyncTask.

Comment: done .. its working!! if you have answered then i could have marked it as answer