# How can i share a mp3 file from internal storage?

Tags: java, android, internal-storage, sharefile

Before any down voting i must say that i searched community and find some answer like [Create and Share a File from Internal Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170386/create-and-share-a-file-from-internal-storage). But i can not understand answers in this topic correctly. This is my code for sharing mp3 file. But it does not send it.

Here the code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + ringtonepath));
sendIntent.setType("audio/*");
Utils.activity.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

and `ringtoepath's` value is /data/data/mypackagename/files/media/mysharesoundmusic.mp3. When i want to share this file using bluetooth a Toast appear with this message that `file mysharesoundmusic.mp3 was not send to devicename`. But when i go to media folder of application i see file in there. Before i used SD card for saving my files and using that i can share files and there is not any problem but as you know some devices has not SD card and because that i need to store files in internal Storage.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're sending that file to another app? Is that the case. 
Maybe you could use FileProvider instead

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html