# The file format is not supported - When a photo is send on WhatsApp

Tags: android, android-intent, share, whatsapp, viber

```
        //Share image to all
        share = (Button)findViewById(R.id.facebook_app_id);
        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/drawable/"+imageRes);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("image/*");

                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent , "Share"));


            }

        });
```

I am trying to build a photo-sharing app. Facebook, Messenger, Skype work perfectly but **Whatsapp and Viber** show an Error (`The file format is not supported`)

Comment: try with this:  String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                    "YOUR_PATH", "Image Description", null);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

Comment: what is "YOUR_PATH" ?you mean << "android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/drawable/"+imageRes>>?

Comment: According to my code is it my Image path is="android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/drawable/"+imageRes and what is Image Description?@Divyesh Patel

Comment: it is just title.

Comment: And what is imageRes? Type and content please!

Comment: ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
image.setImageResource(**imageRes**); @greenapps

Comment: You did not answer my question. Reread please and try again.

Comment: Did you found a answer for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the content type in the share Intent as **image/png**. 
As you said above, that may or may not work for all apps.

The reason is You can not directly share a uri from you apps internal storage (of course the resourses of your app will be always in the internal storage)

There are two ways of achieving this..

Copy your image to external storage then share it from there. See this

Write a Content Provider to share image. For that refer Create and Share a File from Internal Storage

Comment: Can you give me any reference for share image to external storage and Content Provider to share image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170386/create-and-share-a-file-from-internal-storage

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example how to do this:

```
public void shareImageWhatsApp() {

    Bitmap adv = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.adv);
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/jpeg");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    adv.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
        new FileOutputStream(f).write(bytes.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
            Uri.parse( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator+"temporary_file.jpg"));
    if(isPackageInstalled("com.whatsapp",this)){
          share.setPackage("com.whatsapp"); 
          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));

    }else{

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Install Whatsapp", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty bad to convert a png file to a bitmap and then compress it to a stream and using a second stream to write a jpg file. You could instead have copied the drawable directly to file.

Comment: Image File is exist in my Android Emulator Android R . image is showing in imageView perfectly but not share on whatsapp From My App .Always Show File Formate not supported. please help me for this Android R (API 30) . How to Share.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can check 
imageRes with there extension like .jpeg or png
for example
android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/drawable/"+"imageRes.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher_round);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), bitmap, "ic_launcher_round", null);
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(path);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent , "Share"));
```

before this code execute make sure you have to give EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and target and compile sdk higher than lolipop then you have to request permission

Comment: make sure your images in any drawable directory not Minmap

Comment: I use ImageView...   ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
image.setImageResource(imageRes); Is it work, if I use ImageAdapter? According my code "ic_launcher_round"=? what is mine ic_launcher_round?

Comment: your image name which is in the drawable directory