# Android KitKat Don't show taking camera picture on Nexus 4 (Android 4.4)

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a problem when I called my code bellow from android devices, they show the Gallery and Camera, but when I run this code on Nexus 4 (android v4.4, KitKat), it didn't show the camera choosing. It shown only Gallery.

Please help me for this issue

Thanks, :)

```
private Uri    outputFileUri = null;
private String pathImage     = null;

private void chooseImage() {
    // Determine Uri of camera image to save.
    final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + getString(R.string.app_name) + File.separator);
    root.mkdirs();
    final String fname = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

    // Camera.
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // Filesystem.
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");

    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, getString(R.string.title_pick_photo));

    // Add the camera options.
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));

    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, IActivity.PICK_GALLERY);
}
```

Comment: It looks like it's an Android bug. See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827280/on-android-api-19-4-4-the-intent-createchooser-method-causes-intentserviceleak/19827317#19827317 and a bug filed on Android https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61937